# AWK: converting HH:MM:SS;MS

Tags: awk

In part of my awk script, I have the following line:

```
/Running Time/                  {UT=$NF}
```

The value of UT is something like this:

```
0098:34:34:11
```

What I need to do is break it up into days, hours, minutes, seconds.

How do I "echo" the variable `UT` to something where I can split it such that:

```
H=98
M=34
S=34
MS=11
```

One I get it split and assigned to variables, then I can do the math to convert to to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this template, you can find the minutes and seconds in `t[2]` and `t[3]`

```
$ awk '/Running Time/{split($NF,t,":"); 
                     d=int(t[1]/24); h=t[1]%24; 
                     print d,"days,", h, "hours"}'

4 days, 2 hours
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way. And this is it. Thank you.